# Unknown segmentation fault when printing a map

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm getting this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7580d75 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Can I know why the seg fault is occuring?

I am currently printing the content of a C++ map in a file when this error occurs. The map size would be in MBs, could that be a problem?

Comment: Can you update your post to include some relevant code please?

Comment: Use gdb to get a backtrace.

Comment: i did use gdb... this is where is stops....

Comment: There are no other lines of any kind?

Comment: no.. there are no other line.. this is the exact output of gdb i m giving

Comment: Could be memory corruption then. Try valgrind.

Comment: the data is divided into chunks of 13000, when i am breaking at 10000 chunks, its fine but when i let it run in full.. it gives seg fault??
so it could be because of more memory allocation than the program could allow or something else?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: i cant.. its quite lengthy!!.. i m sorry :(
and also part of a larger project..... so cant disclose for nw

Comment: Try simplifying the code so that it becomes possible to post it. Who knows you may figure out the problem. Another stratergy I find useful is commenting bits of the code and seeing what exactly causes the segfault

Answer (score 0):

Try installing debugging symbols for libc, they should be available as a package. In ubuntu they can be found in the package libc-dbg. Gdb should produce better output for you then.

Comment: i doubt looking at core dumps is the right approach, maybe inspecting the code would teach him more

Comment: He's using gdb to get a stack trace, presumably to find out which function he's calling that's segfaulting. This is completely normal debugging.

Comment: indeed thats wht i am doing steve... :)

Comment: Also make sure you have debugging symbols compiled into your own code